# I don't know what to put in the place of β and α in order to print all 3 digit numbers different from 0 and unique

Tags: c

I don't get what I should put in the place of: `"α"` and `"β"` in order to print `all the 3 digit numbers which are different from 0 and from one another.`
It is required to replace those 2 variables, with some code

```
We are entering G(0)!!!
```

It's from an exam paper, I really don't get it, please help.

```
void G(int k)
{int i;
 for(i=1;i<=α;i++)
 { p[k]=i;
 if(β)G(k+1);
 else
 printf("%d%d%d\n",p[0],p[1],p[2]);
 }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196164/discussion-on-question-by-andrei-jarca-i-dont-know-what-to-put-in-the-place-of).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any of this to make sense, it must be that `p` is declared as a global `int` array of dimension at least 3.  I assume for the purposes of this answer that it is in fact so declared.

Note that the function sets `p[k] = i`, but it later reads back only `p[0]`, `p[1]`, and `p[2]`.  This should give you a pretty good idea about what makes sense for expression **β**, which controls whether to recurse (increasing `k`) or print.

Note also that the function sets `p[k] = i`, and that when it reads back those `p[k]` for various `k`, it wants to get values ranging from 1 to 9 (no more and no less).  This should give you a pretty good idea of what expression makes sense for **α**, the inclusive upper bound on `i`.

Having figured those out, it remains to satisfy yourself that the natural substitutions for those expressions indeed produce a resulting function that behaves as required when initially called as `G(0)`.  I suspect that you will find that easier than you did discerning the needed expressions.

(Details are left as an exercise.)

Comment: Oh, ok , it worked, wow man, thanks a lot, can you please explain to me why it worked as a global int and not if it was read inside int main or the function?

Comment: I didn't realise it was important to put it as global int, why is it so important?

Comment: Because I already wrote in the answer that beta could be k<3 and alpha is 9, but didn't put the array global

Comment: @AndreiJarca, `p` cannot be local to `main()`, because then function `G()` could not access it.  It cannot be local to `G()`, because each recursive call needs to access the same `p` array (because the function sets only one element but reads back 3); also because it *isn't* declared in `G()`.  The only alternative is that it be global.

Comment: ok, that makes sense ,thanks a lot